# PHP Class does not take parameters given

Tags: php, class, oop

My class looks like this:

```
class CropAvatar {
    private $src;
    private $data;
    private $file;
    public $srcDir;
    public $dstDir;
    private $dst;
    private $type;
    private $extension;
    private $msg;

    function __construct($src, $data, $file, $source, $destination) {
        $this -> setSrc($src);
        $this -> setData($data);
        $this -> setFile($file);
        $this -> crop($this -> src, $this -> dst, $this -> data);
        $this -> srcDir = $source;
        $this -> dstDir = $destination;
    }
```

And this is how I call

```
$crop = new CropAvatar($_POST['avatar_src'], $_POST['avatar_data'], $_FILES['avatar_file'], $upload_path.'/tmp', $upload_path);
```

Somehow, "srcDir" and "dstDir" values are not set in constructor, no matter if public or private value(!) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: edit with more code, for example your html form

Comment: the post values are set properly in the class, I extended https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar with the 2 values "upload Source" and "desintiontion" directory which are not accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on github link, just create two writable folder 'avatar' and 'upload' under img folder on example.

Comment: Hi, as I said, I extended the github project with 2 dynamic "source" and "desintination" directories. Those directories are writable, but my constructor function does not set the 2 dynamic variables. If I output the "srcDir" or "dstDir" in my error message, it shows me nothing, so nothing set... Why?

Comment: The code on your post doesn’t have any problem, i var_dump it with a $upload_path and it work! @Maxi

Comment: var dump inside the class?

Comment: I just made the values static, so no in constructor. And it works fine. But as soon as I want the parameters to be given it causes trouble...

Comment: Yes, the semi-code is: `$upload_path = '/some/path/here';
$crop = new CropAvatar('avatar_src', 'avatar_data', 'avatar_file', $upload_path$

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($crop);` @Maxi